# Using spread and separate to structure table

Tags: r, format, frequency, tidyr

I have a table like the one below an would like to obtain some frequency statistics, which I have done using the code below.

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(sample(c('Controle','Tratado'),
                              10, replace = T),
                       sample(c(2012,2016),10,T),
                       c('A','B','A','B','C','D','D','A','F','A')))

colnames(df) <- c('Group','Year','Unit')

table <- df %>%
  group_by(Year,Group) %>%
  count(Unit) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%                                               
              mutate(Group ="Total") %>%                         
              group_by(Year, Group) %>%                         
              count(Unit)) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n))
```

However, is there some combination of `tidyr` functions that could help me reshape the table in a way such that the `Unit` observations are on the rows and the I have one column for each of the combination of `Group/Year`?

Also, since maybe the units may not be present on both of the groups and/or years, I would like to leave the cell empty if that was the case.

Thank you very much.

---

**EDIT:** Is there a way to have the final tables in a way that the rows are ordered according to the units that have the largest `n` in 2016? I would just use arrange in the end. However, I would like as well  o paste the `n` and `prop` columns, which makes the results not numeric anymore.

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(sample(c('Controle','Tratado'),
                              10, replace = T),
                       sample(c(2012,2016),10,T),
                       c('A','B','A','B','C','D','D','A','F','A')))

colnames(df) <- c('Group','Year','Unit')

table <- df %>%
  group_by(Year,Group) %>%
  count(Unit) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%                                               
              mutate(Group ="Total") %>%                         
              group_by(Year, Group) %>%                         
              count(Unit)) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n))

is.num <- sapply(table, is.numeric)
table[is.num] <- lapply(table[is.num], round, 4)
table <- table %>%
  mutate(Frequency = paste0(n,' (', 100*prop,'%)'))
```

On other words, can I order the results by units with greater `n` considering the `Total` group in `2016`?

Comment: As in `library(reshape2); dcast(table, Unit ~ Year + Group )`?

Comment: I think it does the job! Thank you

Comment: ps. not related to your question , but dont use `data.frame(cbind(...`, just use `data.frame`

Comment: On a similar note, `table` is a built-in function. It is not advisable to overwrite such functions with your own objects of similar name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tidyr too

```
> table2 <- table%>%gather(type,measurement, -Year,-Group,-Unit)%>%
                    unite(year_group,Year:Group,sep = ":")%>%
                    spread(year_group,measurement)
```

This also preserves the type of measurement,that is, count (n) and prop

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy using `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2); 
dcast(table, Unit ~ Year + Group )
```

This will use one of the remaining columns to fill the values. To keep both:

```
table.m <- melt(table, id.vars = c("Year", "Group", "Unit"))
dcast(table.m, Unit + variable ~ Year + Group )
```

which yields:

```
 Unit variable 2012_Controle 2012_Total 2012_Tratado 2016_Controle 2016_Total 2016_Tratado
1     A        n     1.0000000  3.0000000    2.0000000            NA       1.00          1.0
2     A     prop     0.3333333  0.5000000    0.6666667            NA       0.25          0.5
3     B        n     1.0000000  2.0000000    1.0000000            NA         NA           NA
4     B     prop     0.3333333  0.3333333    0.3333333            NA         NA           NA
5     C        n     1.0000000  1.0000000           NA            NA         NA           NA
6     C     prop     0.3333333  0.1666667           NA            NA         NA           NA
7     D        n            NA         NA           NA           1.0       2.00          1.0
8     D     prop            NA         NA           NA           0.5       0.50          0.5
9     F        n            NA         NA           NA           1.0       1.00           NA
10    F     prop            NA         NA           NA           0.5       0.25           NA
```